# Is the phrase "wide swath" used here idiomatically, or is it just referring to a not thin line of people?

Tags: word-meaning, idioms

> NEW YORK — Perry Ellis is not a brand that makes men nervous or causes them to titter. Even if a work-a-day guy doesn’t wear Perry Ellis clothes, he probably recognizes the name from those times he has wandered through a department store looking to stock up on dress shirts. Perry Ellis is not niche; it is mass. And its creative director, Michael Maccari designed a spring 2016 collection that was welcoming to a **wide swath** of men. Board shorts, crewneck sweaters, lean — but not tight — suits. Rich colors but nothing too psychedelic.

Comment: *Swath* might be considered a questionable word choice, when referring to a broad demographic.

Answer (score 4):

**Wide swath** is an idiomatic phrase and it means something similar to "large variety".

It's often used as:

> "[cut a wide swath](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cut+a+wide+swath)" -
>    - Draw a lot of attention, make a considerable display, as in: *Although he was new to the company, he cut a wide swath*. This metaphoric use of making a big sweep of the scythe in cutting grass survives despite the mechanization of farming and the declining use of the noun swath

In this use, it means that Perry Ellis' 2016 clothing line was designed to attract a large variety of men, since they offered so many different clothing styles.